# Building F# .fsproj on Mac (Mono)

Tags: macos, f#, build, mono, projects-and-solutions

I have an .fsproj (and .sln) from an F# project that was developed on Windows that I want to build on the Mac.

I've built several single-source-file F# programs with Mono, and it's great. Unfortunately, this .fsproj is non-trivial, as there are several source files and a number of references.

Devising the command line to build the project by hand doesn't seem fun.

Is there a tool that will analyze the .sln/.fsproj and give the correct command line? Or perhaps just do the build from the .sln/.fsproj?

I'd like to do this without MonoDevelop or SharpDevelop if possible, though answers along those lines are welcome.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254722/how-can-i-build-a-visual-studio-solution-using-xbuild-from-mono as F# projects should be normal msbuild projects.

Comment: I just tend to use makefiles - once you have written a few it becomes very easy

Comment: @JohnPalmer do you have an example or template to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple makefile that I use

```
FSC=/home/john/FSharp-2.0.0.0/bin/fsc.exe
FSFILES= tokenizer.fs BuildTree.fs symtable.fs mkVMCommands.fs codegen.fs
compiler: compiler.exe

compiler.exe: $(FSFILES)
    $(FSC) --define:LINUX --debug:full --debug+ $(FSFILES) -o:compiler.exe --sig:sigfile.fs

run: compiler
    mono compiler.exe
```

note that the lines after each target - `compiler.exe:...` need to be indented with a `TAB` rather than spaces.  If you need reerences, you just add `-r "Somefile.dll"` to the commandline.

Comment: Interesting. And decidedly more minimal than the .fsproj file. Thanks for sharing this. It seems like having a tool to produce this from the .fsproj would be useful, updating both by hand seems error prone.

Comment: @Harold - I don't know of any automatic tools to convert between .fsproj files and makefiles, but I have found that updating the makefiles by hand is pretty easy

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [xbuild](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build), which directly read `sln` and `fsproj` files and build them on Mono platform.

As @JPW mentioned in the comment, it also [works on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254722/how-can-i-build-a-visual-studio-solution-using-xbuild-from-mono). Although xbuild's F# support seems to be immature, someone has managed to [build F# projects with xbuild on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829805/xbuild-and-f-vs2010-project). Hopefully, it is helpful for you to set up the build environment on Mac.